# typeahead.js при динамическом добавлении полей в форму

Tags: javascript

Использую умный поиск твиттера(typeahead) и динамическое добавление элементов в форму, но поиск работает только в первом . Заметил если добавлю в `$(document).ready(function() {
    add_new_image();
add_new_image(); //еще 1 первый запуск
});` то поле в 2-ух полях работает. Так же почему не появляется иконка удаления около первого поля?  Собственно нужно исправить, чтобы в полях (при добавлении) тоже работал этот умный поиск.... (Заранее спасибо)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ipoisk.by/jquery-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/examples/js/typeahead.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var total = 0;
function add_new_image(){
 total++;
 $('<tr>')
 .attr('id','tr_image_'+total)
 .css({lineHeight:'20px'})
 .append (
  $('<td>')
  .attr('id','td_title_'+total)
  .css({paddingRight:'5px',width:'200px'})
  .append(
   $('<input type="text" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">')
   .css({width:'200px'})
   .attr('id','input_title_'+total)
   .attr('name','input_title_'+total)
  )  
  
 )
 
 .append (
  $('<td>')
  .css({width:'260px'})
  .append (
   $('<span id="progress_'+total+'" class="padding5px"><a  href="#" onclick="$(\'#tr_image_'+total+'\').remove();" class="ico_delete"><img src="delete.png" alt="del" border="0"></a></span>')
  )
 )
 .appendTo('#table_container');
 
}
$(document).ready(function() {
 add_new_image();

});
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.bs-example{
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
.typeahead, .tt-query, .tt-hint {
 border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
 border-radius: 8px;
 font-size: 24px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 outline: medium none;
 padding: 8px 12px;
 width: 396px;
}
.typeahead {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.typeahead:focus {
 border: 2px solid #0097CF;
}
.tt-query {
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
}
.tt-hint {
 color: #999999;
}
.tt-dropdown-menu {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 border-radius: 8px;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 margin-top: 12px;
 padding: 8px 0;
 width: 422px;
}
.tt-suggestion {
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 24px;
 padding: 3px 20px;
}
.tt-suggestion.tt-is-under-cursor {
 background-color: #0097CF;
 color: #FFFFFF;
}
.tt-suggestion p {
 margin: 0;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('input.typeahead').typeahead({
  name: 'accounts',
  local: ['Нюргберг','Париж','Брюссель','Амстердам','Берлин','Лондон','Прага','Дрезден','Здруй','Кудова','Вена','Будапешт','Клагенфурт','Зальцбург','Ливерпуль','Эдинбург','Глазго','Йорк','Брюгге','Антверпен','Величка','Краков','Потсдам','Варшава','Мюнхен','Нюрнберг','Люксембург','Страсбург','Барселона','Мадрид','Бордо','Женева','Авиньон','Салоу','Рим','Флоренция','Верона','Инсбурк','Пиза','Милан','Ватикан','Венеция','Римини','Сорренто','Неаполь','Падуя','Юрмала','Рига','Таллинн','Стокгольм','Вильнюс','Друскининкай','Тракай','Копенгаген','Осло','Трувиль','Довиль','Онфлер','Руан','Нормандия','Сен-мало','Бечичи','Будва','Минск','Дубровник','Бри','Сплит','Казимеж','Сопот','Мальборк','Макарска','Грац','Лихтенштейн','Люцерн','Берн','Цюрих','Бамберг','Регенсбург','Закопане','Ченстохова','Ольштын','Сан-марино','Ремини','Сентендре','Мишкольц','Вернигеороде','Бенилюкс','Вернигероде','Эгер','Сентэндре','Гамбург','Вюрцбург','На таубере','Ротенбург','Нюрнеберг','Харлем','Альберобелло','Бари','Генуя','Сирмионе','Сиена','Парма','Стратсбург','Клангенфурт','Лейпциг','Гослар','Бремен','Боденвердер','Хамельн','Ганновер','Мон сен-мишель','Ницца','Марсель','Лион','Бургундия','Реймс','Кельн','Ватарелоо','Гаага','Кекенхоф','Роттердам','Братислава','Турку','Хельсинки','','Вроцлав','Познань','Торунь','Белосток','Обераммергау','Любек','Баден-баден','Пльзень','Монако','Каркассон','Канны','Волендам','Валеньсия','Кордова','Толедо','Сан-себастьян','Бодо','Этрета','Кольмар','Тулуза','Инсбрук','Лозанна','Веве','Монтре','Люксенбург','Трир','Таррагона','Ля-рошель','Загреб','Кардифф','Грюйер','Гетеборг','Кланегфурт','Линц','Заансе сханс','Нойшванштайн','Саргоса','Сарагоса','Бургос','Леон','Комильяс','Бильбао','Пампалоно','Валенсия','Гранада','Севилья','Лиссабон','Палермо','Помпеи','Гданьск','Лессабон','Дурскининкай','Таллин','Ставнгер','Берген','Гетерборг','Версаль','Страсбуог','Базель','Рененсбург','Афины','Матеоры','Белград','Кобленц','Люнебург','Делфт','Дижон','Метеоры','Турин','Брюсель','Болонья','Петровац','Вернигороде','Тивали','Тале','Кведлинбург','Лугано','Патры','Мон-сен-мишель','Твоили','Тиволи','Сан себастьян','Оденсе','Эрфрут','Дельфт','Рига ','Вадуц','Нюрнбрег','Мишкольц-тапольца','Токай','Сигишоара','Брашов','Бран','Синая','Бухарест','Сибиу','Мёнтре','Мюнхер','Эль-эскориал','Фигерас','Кутна гора','Телч','Брно','Ватерлоо','Штайн ам райн','Мейринген','Беллинцона','Нюрнгберг','Веймар','Онфлера','Прато','Карловы вары','Кордоба','Зальцкамергут','Сентэдре','Салоники','Сегед','Веспрем','Солнечный берег','Золотые пески','Эстергом','Вишеград','Сэнтендре','Ротенбург-на-таубере','Поречь','Магдебург','Аахен','Кохем','Рюдерсхайм','Санкт-петербург','Царское село','Кронштадт','Павловск','Петергоф','Выборг','Кенингштайн','Лодзь','Нидзица','Ольштынек','Решель','Кентшин','Герлож','Сигулда','Турайда','Петергроф','Пушкин','Москва','Петрозаводск','Кондопога','Гирвас','Сортавала','Смоленск','Сергиев посад','Александров','Владимир','Суздаль','Боголюбово','Ростов','Переславль','Залесский','Нерли','Великий новгород','Псков','Изборск','Печоры','Киев','Чернигов','Львов','Ужгород','Черновцы','Каменец-подольский','Хотин','Одесса','Гент','Вевей','Курорт св. константин и елена','Кранево','Кромержиж','Санкт-перербург','Ллорет де мар','Мукачево','Друскининскай','Кошице','Бардеёв','Левоча','Каунас','Лиепая','Прешов','Бардеев','Попрад','Будва петровац','Будва/бечичи','Минск – прага – мюнхен – баварские замки* - цюрих ','Дрезден – лейпциг* — прага','Прага – вена* – замок чешский штернберк – дрезден*','Рускеала','Кижи','Гривас','Кивач','Париж-версаль*-бордо-сент-эмильон*-сан-себастьян-п','Вена – венеция – флоренция – сиена* – рим – ватика','Зальцбург - милан - монако -берн – люцерн - нюрнбе','Дрезден - милан - монако - отдых в испании (ллорет','Валаам','Берлин-амстердам-лондон-стрэтфорд-на-эйвоне-данфер','Кентербери-лондон- стретфорд-на-эйвоне-гретна грин','Лондон – париж – дрезден','Потсдам– амстердам- брюссель*-париж (3 дня) –кельн','Отдых на лазурном берегу (7ночей). потсдам – амсте','Берлин– амстердам-брюссель- париж –кельн','Берлин – амстердам – париж– версаль* – ницца – мон','Берлин – брюгге – нормандия (руан – онфлер – довил','Веймар – париж – долина луары – тулуза – отдых в и','Прага – люцерн – берн – авиньон – гарский мост*– о','Рига – стокгольм – копенгаген – гамбург – трир – л','Вена - падуя - рим - ватикан - неаполь - бари - ла','Отдых на соррентийском полуострове. вена–венеция–р','Дрезден – милан – пиза – флоренция – рим – ватикан','Зальцбург - инсбрук - музей сваровски* - верона - ','Мишкольц-будапешт','Будапешт – белград – метеоры – афины – салоники – ','Германия-дания. гамбург-любек*-копенгаген-замки да','Прага-нюрнберг-мюнхен-замки нойшванштайн* и линдер','Мюнхен - замок нойшванштайн - берн - цюрих - рейнс','Мальборк -гданьск-сопот','Таллинн – стокгольм – гётеборг – осло – берген – с','Бамберг- мец- дижон- клермон- ферран- перигё-сан-с','Минск-болгария(балчик-албена-кранево-золотые пески','Минск - будапешт - прага - вена','Ченстахова','Минск - мукачево - чинадиево - львов - минск','Вена - венеция - рим - ватикан - чивитавеккья - те','Бамберг – люцерн – лугано – милан – отдых на лигур','Амбуаз','Витебск','Полоцк','Вильнюс-тракай','Геленджик','Гелегджик','Брест','Версаль*','Истрия','Любляна','Рануа','Рованиеми','Альта','Тромсё','Тролльфьорд','Тронхейм','Чески-крумлов','Хэвис','Сан-джиминьяно','Соренто','Брест.','Новогрудок','Заосье','Коссово','Ружаны','Пружаны','Стрельно','Мотоль','Вороцевичи','Амстредам','Кюккенхоф','Фредериксборг','Фьорды','Флам','Дроттнингхольм','Прешев','Люблин','Диснейленд','Раквере','Пярну','Баден','Псков - изборск','Псков изборск','Минск санкт-петербург','Берлин – амстердам – париж – диснейленд* – дрезден','Мишкольц – будапешт — излучина дуная (эстегом, виш','Ротердам','Бавария','Гродно','Коробчицы','Кёльн','Дюссельдорф','Меречевщина','Чижевщина','Здитово','Матеевичи','Малые сехновичи','Цесис','Хорватия','Аместердам','Черногория','Шиофок','Тихань','Пореч','Плзень','Кёнигсбург','Майнц','Баден баден','Янтар','Бар','Бастай','Чешский крумлов','Швейцарская ривьера','Нюнберг','Гдыня','Ворцлав','Мир','Несвиж','Нижна','Лида','Березовка','Пинск','Молодово','Закозель','Балатон','Кобрин','Леба','Монте карло','Паланга','Петразаводск','Копнгаген','Задар*','Туров','Литва','Бяла подляска','Париж-амстердам','Будапеш','Анапа','Станицы благовещенская','Гомель','Санкт-петербурга','Кабардинка','Питер','Гатчина','Фонтенбло*','Кeкенхоф*','Верона*','Брюссель*','Белград*','Эдипсос','Будапешт ','Кижи*','Любек*','Гамбур','Братислава*','Вена*','Заансе сханс*','Краков*','Верона *','Пиза*','Помпеи*','Неаполь*','Сентендре*','Витязево','Лебу','Дрезден*','Линдерхоф','Обераммергау*','Лейпци','Пиерия','Халкидики','Освенцим','Минск-варшава-минск','Австрия, германия, италия, нидерланды, польша, фра','Россия','Бельгия, германия, нидерланды, люксембург','Австрия, венгрия, италия, польша, черногория','Бельгия, германия, испания, франция, чехия, швейца','Германия','Вена — зальцбург — зальцкамергут* — инсбрук* — муз','Германия, италия, швейцария','Польша, латвия, дания, норвегия, швеция','Австрия, бельгия, германия, испания, нидерланды, п','Германия, польша','Австрия, германия, чехия','Австрия, италия, польша, ватикан','Венецйия','Ллорет-де-мар','Лейпциг*','Бремен*','Сиена*','Чивитавеккья','Термы сатурния','Лукка','Онфлёр','Сан-марино*','Беломорск','Успенск','Вале марсель','Трир*','Олива','Соловки','Ватнавалок','Тапольца','Клайпеда','Люцерне','Вышеград','Сентендер','Венецию','Нижний город','Затока','Берлин-брюссель-йорк-эдинбург-кардифф-лондон-амсте','Краков – величка','Террачина','Верхний город','Берлин - париж - диснейлэнд - прага','Прага - карловы вары* - дрезден','Мистическая прага','Варшава берлин потсдам минск','Берлин париж прага','Здравнево','Мосар','Удело','Глубокое','Могилев','Хатынь','Жыровичи','Слоним','Монакко','Коста брава','Фпгерасса','Канн','Милана','Фонтенбло','Мон сен мишель',' версаль','Констанц','Инсбург','Чешский штернберг','Долина рейна','Эрфурт','Зельцбург','Клагенфурд','Венский лес','Орша','Поставы','Сынковичи',' реймс','Сэнтэнре','Излучина дуная','Лепциг','Раз1','Три1','Два','Рочестер','Кентербери','Мейсен','Мон сель-мишель','Ледницко','Сочи','Сандомеж','Цетине','Кёкенхоф','Грасс','Макарску','Интерлакен','Коста','Брава','Жирона','Люневиль','Нанси','Эперне','Мец','Белосток ','Гальштадт','Costa brava','Кежмарок','Липтовский микулаш','Мальборк ','Андриатика','1','Мундус','Мини','Помпе','Виндзор','Один1','Пять1','Задар','Чехия','Малинска','Нивица','Адриатическое поборежье','Муднус','Андора','Таполица','Луганово','Южная моравия','Бальчик','Цюхих','Монтрё','Белый дунаец','Макарска ривьера','Трогир','Котор','Плитвицкие озера','Фрагонар','Барселона*','Лозана','Долина реки неретва','Макарская ривьера','Хевиз','Риека','Пула','Прога','Баутцен','Альбрехтбург','Морицбург','Гурзуф','Трансильвания','Стамбул','Кушадасы','Пловдив','София','Хайдусобосло','Дебрецен','Велико-тырново','Фигейрас','Санремо','Коблево','Ильичевск','Шамони','Анси','Ньиредьхаза','Шопрон','Бюкфюрдё','Санкт-питербург','Карловы-вары','Анкона','Каринтия','Сан-ремо','Фегерас','Яремче','Буковель','Сан марино','Выше град','Венеция.','Равенна','Эвия']
 });
});  
</script>
<form action="add.php" method="post">
 <table id="table_container">
  <tr>
   <td width="100px" colspan="2"><strong>Вывод</strong></td>
   
  </tr>
 </table>
  <br/>
 <input type="button" value="Добавить поле" id="add" onclick="add_new_image();">
 
 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

P.S для проверки к примеру слово  Москва

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что при добавлении нового поля не инициализируется `typeahead` для созданного `<input>`. То есть после добавления `<input>` в HTML страницы необходимо "применить" к нему `.typeahead()`.

Вариант решения проблемы с минимальными изменениями в коде:

1. Сохраняем созданный `<input>` в переменную:

   ```
   var jInput = $('<input type="text" class="typeahead tt-query" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false">')
       .css({ width: '200px' })
       .attr('id', 'input_title_' + total)
       .attr('name', 'input_title_' + total);
   ```
2. Добавляем его в созданный `<td>` теперь так:

   ```
   $('<td>')
       .attr('id', 'td_title_' + total)
       .css({ paddingRight: '5px', width: '200px' })
       .append(jInput)
   ```
3. Код инициализации `typeahead` (тот, что внутри `document.ready`) меняем на такой:

   ```
   function addTypeahead(jElement) {
       jElement.typeahead({
           name: 'accounts',
           local: [ куча элементов ]
       });
   };
   ```
4. В конец функции `add_new_image` (главное, что после `.appendTo('#table_container')`) добавляем:

   ```
     addTypeahead(jInput);
   ```

[Рабочий пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Le9uxLfz/).

Comment: Спасибо понял как сделать!

Comment: @jeday на здоровье.